# Get from Dictionary which is an instance of Object

Tags: c#, .net, list, object

I'm using a function which return an Object, and the Object is a List.
I can't use index for getting the properties.

**My Code:**

Get the Object:

```
Object myObject = x.ImportDataFromX(Int32.Parse(txtX.Text),dataGViewX.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString());
```

Use the Index:

```
dataGViewX.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value = myObject[5]; //ERROR
```

The Function:

```
Public Function ImportDataFromX(ByVal ClientID As Integer, ByVal BarcodeID As String) As Object
        Dim DrByBarcode As DataTable = GetTable("select MainInfo,FromNumber,ToNumber,FromDate,ToDate,BeurDate,Field1,Field2,Field3 from BoxsInfo inner join TblBoxsPreIndex on BoxsInfoID=[BoxsInfo].id where TblBoxsPreIndex.[ClientId]=" & ClientID & " and [FormId]=-5000 and TblBoxsPreIndex.BarcodeID='" & BarcodeID & "'")

        Select Case DrByBarcode.Rows.Count
            Case 0
                Return "can't find  record to barcode: " & BarcodeID
            Case 1
                Dim Dr As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
                Dr.Add("MainInfo", IIf(IsDBNull(DrByBarcode.Rows(0).Item("MainInfo")), "", DrByBarcode.Rows(0).Item("MainInfo")))
                Dr.Add("FromNumber", IIf(IsDBNull(DrByBarcode.Rows(0).Item("FromNumber")), "", DrByBarcode.Rows(0).Item("FromNumber")))
                Dr.Add("ToNumber", IIf(IsDBNull(DrByBarcode.Rows(0).Item("ToNumber")), "", DrByBarcode.Rows(0).Item("ToNumber")))
                Dr.Add("FromDate", IIf(IsDBNull(DrByBarcode.Rows(0).Item("FromDate")), "", DrByBarcode.Rows(0).Item("FromDate")))
                Dr.Add("ToDate", IIf(IsDBNull(DrByBarcode.Rows(0).Item("ToDate")), "", DrByBarcode.Rows(0).Item("ToDate")))
                Dr.Add("BeurDate", IIf(IsDBNull(DrByBarcode.Rows(0).Item("BeurDate")), "", DrByBarcode.Rows(0).Item("BeurDate")))
                Dr.Add("Field1", IIf(IsDBNull(DrByBarcode.Rows(0).Item("Field1")), "", DrByBarcode.Rows(0).Item("Field1")))
                Dr.Add("Field2", IIf(IsDBNull(DrByBarcode.Rows(0).Item("Field2")), "", DrByBarcode.Rows(0).Item("Field2")))
                Dr.Add("Field3", IIf(IsDBNull(DrByBarcode.Rows(0).Item("Field3")), "", DrByBarcode.Rows(0).Item("Field3")))


                Return Dr

            Case > 1
                Return " barcode" & BarcodeID & "duplicate"
        End Select
    End Function
```

What should I do?

Comment: Why is it an `Object`? Can't you cast it to a more specific type?

Comment: What does `ImportDataFromX`  return?

Comment: @CodeCaster @SᴇM. The function ImportDataFromX return `Object`, and it is from a reference that I use.

Comment: @yo Can you share `ImportDataFromX` code?

Comment: @SᴇM. I've added.

Comment: @yo Check my answer, see if it helps.

Comment: @SᴇM. I'm in middle of checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your values by casting your `object` to `Dictionary`:

```
dataGViewX.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value = ((Dictionary<string, string>)myObject)["BeurDate"];
```

or

```
dataGViewX.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value = (myObject as Dictionary<string, string>)["BeurDate"];
```

If you want to get your value by index, you can use `ElementAt`:

```
dataGViewX.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value = ((Dictionary<string, string>)myObject).Values.ElementAt(5);
```

But bear in mind that the order of `Dictionary` is not guaranteed. So instead of using an index of your value, use your `Dictionary` key. Or you can use  [OrderedDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: @yo Also, if you change the return type of your function in VB from `Object` to `Dictionary(Of String, String)`, you should be able (I'm not sure) to get your values without casting.

Comment: Yes, but while not found, the function return a string.